# Going through a JSON document array in Javascript & JQuery with KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Right now I have the following JSON document:

```
[
   {
      "price":"1.0",
      "shares":13
   },
   {
      "price":"2.0",
      "shares":5
   },
   {
      "price":"3.0",
      "shares":24
   }
]
```

If someone wants 20 shares, I want to return the lowest price possible for 20 shares. In this case its:

13 shares at $1 ($13)

5 shares at $2 ($10)

2 shares at $3 ($6)

the total cost is $29

The specific knockout code I have to do this gets the 20 shares from a previously defined (and working) this.wantedShares() binding.

code:

```
    this.totalCost = ko.computed(function(){                
            var wantedShares = this.wantedShares();
            var shareCounter = 0.00;
            var counter = 0;
            var totalPrice = 0.00;

            $.getJSON("sell.json", function(json){  
                $.each(json, function() {
                    if(shareCounter <= wantedShares){
                    shareCounter = shareCounter + json[counter].shares;
                    totalPrice = totalPrice + (json[counter].price * json[counter].shares);
                    counter++;
                    }
                });
            });
            return totalPrice;
    }, this);
```

This code doesn't work, whatever is happening, its not updating totalPrice at all - it remains at 0. Any ideas?

Comment: Let's see the rest of your view model.

Comment: Elliot, I posted an answer that shows the proper code, along with a working JSFiddle. Did that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is asynchronous so your return will fire before the ajax is complete

Answer (score 1):

Your $.getJSON function is asynchronous, and when it returns it performs your callback, but in the meanwhile you have already returned totalPrice of 0.  I would recommend switching to a subscribe on wantedShares and making totalPrice an observable that you set in the callback.

Answer (score 1):

$.getJSON is an asynchronous request. The 'A' in "AJAX" = asynchronous.

When Knockout evaluates your computed value, it's not going to wait for the asynchronous operation to complete. Therefore, it will always return 0.

Bottom line: don't do AJAX requests inside your computed value.

Instead, do something like this:

```
// Fetch all the shares asynchronously.
var allShares = ko.observableArray();
$.getJSON("sell.json", function(shares) { allShares(shares); });

// The totalCost observable is dependent on the allShares.
// When allShares changes asynchronously, totalCost will get re-evaluated.
var totalCost = ko.computed(function() {              
   var shareCounter = 0.00;
   var totalPrice = 0.00;

   allShares().each(function(share) {
       if(shareCounter <= wantedShares().length) {
           shareCounter = shareCounter + share.shares;
           totalPrice = totalPrice + (share.price * share.shares);
       }
   });
});
```

I've created [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sYWRx/) that shows it working.